# If $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a continous function and $K$ is compact in $\mathbb{R}$, $f|_K$ is lipschitz?

Tags: real-analysis

If $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a continous function and $K$ is compact in $\mathbb{R}$, is  $f|_K$  lipschitz?

Comment: Continuously differentiable would suffice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. Consider $x\mapsto \sqrt x$; extend to $x<0$ by reflecting throught the $y$-axis, take $K=[-1,1]$.

Comment: AKA $x\mapsto \sqrt{\left|x\right|}$.